# When is an index justified on a small reference table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

In my schema I have lots of small reference tables like this

```
CREATE TABLE category 
(
     category VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY
);
```

which will contain between 20-250 rows.

I'm aware that using an INDEX means INSERT performance will be slightly impacted, as well as the additional disk space use.  Obviously I don't care at all about either of these because my reference tables are tiny and seldom change.

I'm only concerned about the performance of high frequency INSERTs on the main table with many columns which reference these numerous small tables.

Suppose I INSERT a row to my main table; in order to enforce a given REFERENCE constraint, is Postgres required to perform a kind of SELECT on the referenced table, to check the value is present?

If so, then even though the tables are very small, is an index justified on pretty much every tiny table, given I'm anticipating a high enough frequency of inserts into the main table?

Or am I barking up the wrong tree? (no pun intended)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An explicit index is justified but not necessary.  The referencing column should be declared as a primary key.  This will automatically create an index.  Why do you want a primary key?  Referential integrity.  You want to be sure that the tables that reference such tables have correct values.

I would suggest that you use a 2-byte or 4-byte number as the primary key.  This reduces the overhead in other tables that reference the reference tables.  Also, indexes are slightly more efficient when the keys are fixed length versus variable length.

So, I would suggest something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE category (
    categoryId smallint generated always as identity primary key
    category VARCHAR unique
);
```